# How can I show the negative gradient of centrifugal potential equals centrifugal force?

Tags: forces, potential, vectors

Given, the centrifugal potential is

$$V = -m\frac{1}{2} \left\lVert\ \vec w\ \times \vec r\ \right\rVert^2 $$

I simplified,

$$V = -m\frac{1}{2} (w^2 + r^2) $$

,converted to Cartesian

$$V = -m\frac{1}{2} [w^2 + (x^2+y^2+z^2) ] $$

,and obtained from the negative gradient:

$$\vec F\ =   m< w^2xsin^2\theta ~~\hat x\ ,~w^2ysin^2\theta ~~\hat y\ ,w^2zsin^2\theta 
~~\hat z\ >$$

I'm having trouble seeing how this regains:

$$\vec F\ = m[\vec w\ \times (\vec w\ \times\vec r)]  $$

Comment: Why does your force vector have only two components?

Comment: @probably_someone I have revised the post.

Comment: Your conversion to Cartesian coordinates is also incorrect.

Comment: If $\vec{w}$ does not lie along the $z$ axis, the $z$-component of $\nabla V$ will be nonzero.

Comment: note that: $\| \vec{w} \times \vec{r} \|^2 \neq ( \| \vec{w} \|^2 + \| \vec{r} \|^2 ) = (w^2+r^2)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a potential $V=-\frac{1}{2}||\vec{w}\times\vec{r}||^2=-\frac{1}{2}w^2r^2\sin^2\theta_{wr}$, where we have used only the definition of the cross product, and where $\theta_{wr}$ is the angle between $\vec{w}$ and $\vec{r}$. Note that $\theta_{wr}$ is *not* necessarily equivalent to the angle $\theta$ in spherical coordinates, unless $\vec{w}$ is aligned with the $z$-axis. So, **assuming that $\vec{w}=w\hat{z}=\langle 0,0,w\rangle$ and therefore $\theta_{wr}=\theta$**, we first convert $V=-\frac{1}{2}w^2r^2\sin^2\theta$ (which is now expressed entirely in spherical coordinates) into Cartesian coordinates. Noting that $\sin{\theta}=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{r}$ due to trigonometry, we have that

$$V=-\frac{1}{2}w^2r^2\frac{x^2+y^2}{r^2}=-\frac{1}{2}w^2(x^2+y^2)$$

and therefore

$$-\nabla V=\vec{F}=(w^2x)\hat{x}+(w^2y)\hat{y}=\langle w^2x,w^2y,0\rangle$$

in whichever notation you prefer.

Now, consider the quantity $\vec{w}\times(\vec{w}\times\vec{r})$, still assuming that $\vec{w}=w\hat{z}$. We evaluate directly, noting that $\vec{r}=x\hat{x}+y\hat{y}+z\hat{z}=\langle x,y,z\rangle$:

$$\vec{w}\times(\vec{w}\times\vec{r})=\vec{w}\times\langle-wy,wx,0\rangle=\langle w^2x,w^2y,0\rangle$$

and therefore $-\nabla V = \vec{F} = \vec{w}\times(\vec{w}\times\vec{r})$.

Comment: The conversions from Cartesian to spherical coordinates are as follows: $x=r\sin\theta\cos\phi$, $y=r\sin\theta\sin\phi$, and $z=r\cos\theta$. Keeping in mind that $\sin^2\phi+\cos^2\phi=1$, compute $x^2+y^2$ and solve for $\sin\theta$. Alternatively, draw a triangle connecting the origin, the point, and a point of the same height on the $z$-axis. The angle between the z-axis and the hypotenuse is $\theta$; solve for $\sin\theta$.